# LibGDX Actor Grouping

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm wanting to create an object that contains a body and a head that is linked to that. If I rotate the parent object, the child object needs to rotate with it. I also need the ability to go in and rotate the child without effecting the parent. I'm trying to do this using groups, but I'm getting mixed up on how to set this up. Here is structure I'm trying to build:

> Character -> Body -> Head

So if I do a rotate on Character, Body and Head move. If I rotate Body, the head keeps its position relative to the body. I know that Box2d can do this, but I really just want to keep it this simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just over thinking this. Basically all I had to do was create a Character class that extends Group, then inside that, just create a Head object which extends Image and a Body object that extends Image. From there, I just animated those in the Character.act method. My Screen then just adds Character to the stage.